# Spring Boot migration script syntax problems due to H2 version update

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, h2

I've updated the version of H2 database (used only for testing) from `1.4.196` to `2.1.210` and the migration scripts now fails due to syntax errors.

Migration scripts are 2 types - pre (pure SQL) and post liquibase (XML based) introduction to the project.

Here is what is defiend in the test `yaml` config:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;Mode=Oracle
    platform: h2  // changed to sql.init.platform: h2

  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
```

I've tryed to add `spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver` and `spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect` proerpties, but that did not do the trick.

I very mych tink it is due to some configuration difference between the two version `1.4` and `2.1`

**COMMENT REPLY**

The liquibase changeset that causes the error:

```
<changeSet id="20191112130000-1" author="zdravko">
    <dropColumn tableName="NEWS_CONTENT" columnName="DAY"/>
</changeSet>
```

Error itself:

```
Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Syntax error in SQL statement "ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.NEWS_CONTENT DROP COLUMN [*]DAY"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.NEWS_CONTENT DROP COLUMN DAY [42001-210] [Failed SQL: (42001) ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.NEWS_CONTENT DROP COLUMN DAY]
```

Comment: There are breaking changes in H2 2.0 in terms of the SQL that it supports. What's the failure that you're getting and is it occurring when running your pure SQL scripts or the SQL that Liquibase generates from the XML changelog?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I've edited the post with the liquibase changeset that makes problem

Answer (score 4):

`DAY` is a keyword in H2 and it is also a reserved word in the SQL Standard (even in completely outdated SQL-92 and in all newer versions), it means it cannot be used as unquoted identifier.

Liquibase supports H2 2.x.y and its keywords since the version 4.7.0, if you use some older version, you need to upgrade. If you use this or newer version, something is going wrong.

In that case you can check `objectQuotingStrategy` and use `QUOTE_ALL_OBJECTS`:

https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/config-ref/objectquotingstrategy.html

Also you can add `;NON_KEYWORDS=DAY` to JDBC URL of H2, but it would be better to avoid it if you can, this setting isn't very reliable and should be used only when you can't do anything else.